# Как сделать правильную пагинацию в парсере?

Tags: python, парсер, pagination

Есть код парсера сайта авито, определённой категории машин, в данном случае Honda. В данном регионе на момент написания этого вопроса имеется 4 страницы с машинами Honda. Пагинацию я сделал вот таким образом, она работает, но при условии, что я знаю сколько страниц всего.

```
headers = {'accept': '*/*',
           'user-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) '
                         'Chrome/78.0.3904.97 Safari/537.36'}

base_url = 'https://www.avito.ru/belgorod/avtomobili/honda?&cd=1&radius=200'


def avito_pars(url, headers, requests=requests):
    car = []
    urls = []
    session = requests.Session()
    requests = session.get(url, headers=headers)
    if requests.status_code == 200:
        print('Yes')
        pars = bs(requests.content, 'lxml')
        try:
            pagination = pars.find_all('a', attrs={'class': 'pagination-page'})
            count = int(pagination[3].text)
            for i in range(1, count + 1):
                url = f'https://www.avito.ru/belgorod/avtomobili/honda?p={i}&cd=1&radius=200'
                if url not in urls:
                    urls.append(url)
        except:
            pass
```

Проблема заключается вот в чём :

[image: Пагинация авито]

В слове **"Последняя".** Если бы там была **цифра,** то в коде я мог бы написать так

```
count = int(pagination[-1].text)
```

И цикл просто по **count**, это сработало бы и проблем не было. Но как решить эту проблему нормально ?

Comment: 1. Вытащите из href последнего элемента нужное вам число регулярным выражением
2. Каждый раз проверять отдает ли страница ответ 200

Comment: int(pagination[-2].text) + 1

Comment: @vadimvaduxa Этот метод не работает, если 50 страниц, на авито показывается только 1 по 10, потом "последняя"